# Ghostscript not creating output PDF file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm having trouble writing an output PDF file with Ghostscript. It is run in a batch script. When not running in batch mode (without `-o` or `-dBATCH`), the result pages are shown in the output window.

However, there is no way I can get Ghostscript to write the result to a PDF output file.

Here's the line calling gs:

```
gs -o out.pdf 
   -sDevice=pdfwrite
   -dColorImageResolution=30 
   -dGrayImageResolution=30
   -dMonoImageResolution=30
   -dCompressFonts=true
   test.pdf
```

The file is there:

```
user:~/test> ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 212033 22. Jan 15:27 test.pdf
```

In GhostView's output, there is nothing helpful:

```
Processing pages 1 through 577.
Page 1
Loading ... font from ... done.
Page 2
Page 3
Page ...
```

If anyone could point me to what I forget in order for Ghostscript to actually write the result to the specified file, that would very helpful.

Comment: Are you saying that out.pdf does not exist afterwards ?

Comment: Use -sDEVICE=pdfwrite instead of -sDevice, its case sensitive

Comment: Thanks! That worked...